# Push external json data into selectbox dynamically

Tags: jquery, json

I wanted to use the json data as external (.json) file to push the values into selectbox dynamically.

Appreciate for any help...

Comment: Demo JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vaq9N/

Comment: Create one .json file and paste your json object's value in that.Add that file into your project folder,now with the use of jquery($.getJSON();) you can load data of .json file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion :)

```
$.getJSON( "/test.json", function( data ) {
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    $("#mySelectBox").push( "<option name='" + val + '>" + val + "</option>" );
  });
});
```

-- EDIT

```
function loadlist(selobj, url) {
    selobj.empty();
    selobj.append('<option value="0">--Select Category--</option>');
    $.getJSON(url, function( data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, e) {
        console.log(e);
        selobj.append( "<option name='" + e.id + "'>" + e.name + "</option>" );
      });
    });

}
loadlist($('select#category'), 'http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/random.json');
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion.... Please find the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/vaq9N/1/   -I am not getting the data from external json..

Comment: My new solution will not work in a JS fiddle, but will work on your site. The problem with loading data through a JS fiddle is that you get errors with permissions on the HTTP cross site requests.

Comment: @RamkumarMani I would suggest you to go with woverton answer.

Comment: Currently I am developing a HTML-POC for a project...I have used in my project..but it didn't works... How to resolve this error - "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/random.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access?" ... Please let me know your inputs...thanks

Comment: The can not be fixed from your code. You need to edit the config for the web server where http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/random.json is set to allow cross site requests

Comment: You need `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin “*”` in the `vhosts.conf` for whatever version of apache you are using

Comment: Sorry if that has halted your development. Its a real pain.

Comment: You can have a local version of that json and use it though :)

Comment: Did that work? If so can you mark an answer as done :)

Comment: I have the local copy of that json file and try to pull the data...but now I am getting an error saying that "Origin is null.."

Comment: Are you accessing it from a file rather than a web server? If so, you may need to run chrome like this: `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score -1):

You would need to make your backend solution to return that external JSON file when requested for it. As far as I know using javascript it is not possible to load an external file and use that data.

Depending on your situation you can also move that javascript variable to an external file and load that as a script to the document you are creating. That won't be a valid JSON file itself but could act as a solution if requesting JSON from backend is not a solution.

Comment: @Xantier It is possible to load data of external ".json" file using jquery.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I would be interested in reading more information about this, could you point me to the correct direction?